# Replace the image of a facebook post with Python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, python-requests

There is a post on my facebook page which has some text and an image, and I would like to replace the image with another one saved on my computer.

Using [facebook graph API](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#put-object) (but feel free to suggest other packages) I'm able to easily update/edit the text of the post

```
import facebook
page_token = '...'
fb = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token = page_token, version="2.12")
page_id = '...'
post_id = '...'
fb.put_object(parent_object = page_id + '_' + post_id,
              connection_name = '',
              message = 'new text')
```

while I'm struggling to understand how to replace/update the image of the post. I'm pretty sure that `put_object` is the function to use for this task too, but I don't know which parameters to use (and the documentation above is not helpful). The image I want to upload is stored in the same folder of the python script, this is what I tried so far

```
fb.put_object(parent_object = page_id + '_' + post_id,
              connection_name = '',
              message = 'new text',
              source = open('out.png', 'rb'))
```

and

```
fb.put_object(parent_object = page_id + '_' + post_id,
              connection_name = '',
              message = 'new text',
              object_attachment = open('out.png', 'rb'))
```

but none of them works (python does not return errors though). Any hints? Are there other packages with which this task can be accomplished (for example `requests`)?

p.s. these are the permission of the app I created using the developers account

```
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_engagement
```

Comment: You can not upload a photo directly in the post creation or update process. If you check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#pubfields you see that `object_attachment` requires the ID of an already existing photo - so you would have to upload that separately first.

Comment: @CBroe thanks, I wonder maybe that's true only for the specific parameter `object_attachment`, because I now for sure that it is possible to create a post and attach a local image by simply using the `put_photo` function: that is `fb.put_photo(parent_object='...', image=open('...', 'rb'), message='...')`), so I guess that this is possible for updating the post too

Comment: Then I think you are talking about a Photo object, and not a Post, to begin with. I don’t think you can “update” the image of those - because the image _is_ the essential part of that type of object.

Comment: @CBroe I don't know, let me search. I'll explain in detail the situation. Few days ago I created a post (on my FB page) containing only text, then I added an image (from my pc) to the post, and then I replaced that image with another one (from my pc), all this was done "by hand" without python. Now I would like to simply replace that image with another one but using Python, I think it can be done since it is possible to do it manually.

Comment: The API is not a complete 1:1 mapping of UI functionality, so just because something is possible via their UI, does not necessarily mean there _must_ be a way to do it via API as well in all instances. And when it comes to _updating_ stuff, you can usually expect not to have any more possibilities there, then you have when _creating_ something via API in the first place.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#pubfields lists what is available when creating a post, `message` is one of the fields, and that worked, but for the image, I don’t see anything else but `object_attachment`. (`child_attachments` can have an additional image, but those are _links_ to begin with, and that doesn’t appear to be what you are having here, from the description so far.)

Comment: @CBroe thank you very much for your help, I'm reading that page right now but I think there is a difference between the official documentation and the facebook graph API documentation for python, because as I said before with python is really easy to create a new post containing text and a local image, just use `fb.put_photo(parent_object=pageid, image=open('image.png', 'rb'), message='something'))` and a new post will be created having `something` as text and `image.png` as image. I used this command several times so it works. I don't know why is not written in the page you linked.

Comment: _“I don't know why is not written in the page you linked.”_ - because that is the actual API documentation. There is no such thing as a “Graph API for python” - just because you might be using a particular library or SDK that offers some wrapper functions around the functionality, doesn’t mean that it is not making the same requests in the background, as they are explained in the official API documentation to begin with. No such library or SDK _can_ do any things, that the underlying API does not support in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe i see what you mean, but so since it is possible with the graph API, it means that the graph API uses one of the Fields in the page you linked to upload the photo. Or maybe we have to look at the PagePost https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-post

Comment: Well page posts have `attached_media` listed as one of the updatable fields, but even that requires a Facebook media ID. _“it means that the graph API uses one of the Fields in the page you linked to upload the photo”_ - no, it must not mean that, it can also mean that your library uploads a photo first, and then attaches it to the post it makes afterwards.